# Domain restricted authentication on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I've recently deployed a GAE application (namely http://www.stashboard.org/) in order to help manage my company's application pool.

In order not to publish the pool's status tout everyone (customers, other companies...) i wish to allow access only to those who log in with their corporate account (ie : user@mycompany.com).

The domain "mycompany.com" is not managed by google.

When I set the Authentication Type to "Google Apps domain" i can no longer log in to the app, and i get a Error 500 instead:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
> If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
> error message and the query that caused it.

The following error is logged:

> 2013-10-21 14:42:57.856 /admin 500 55ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
> 194.206.149.66 - - [21/Oct/2013:05:42:57 -0700] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36"
> "xxxxxx.appspot.com" ms=56 cpu_ms=0 app_engine_release=1.8.6  W
> 2013-10-21 14:42:57.856
>
> Authentication for the Google Apps domain
> mycompany.com can only be performed when requests are served from a
> subdomain of that domain or it has been approved through the Google
> Apps Control Panel. See
> https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth

The linked documentation doesn't help me much, and the admin in charge of Google Apps doesn't find how to "approve" the domain (appspot.com i guess) in the control panel.

FYI: this is my first time working with GAE, and that makes me the most experienced GAE user in my company... so yeah we're pretty clueless here.

Comment: You are saying that the domain is not managed by Google and then your Google Apps admin can't find stuff.. so my question is, is mycompany.com managed by Google Apps or not?

Comment: You may try with this. https://support.google.com/a/answer/45690?hl=en

Comment: @Lipis: The domain name isn't managed by google, but my company still uses Gapps.

Comment: @girardid then I'm afraid that you'll have to connect somehow the two.. did you manage to run the gae app on custom domain?

Comment: I didn't, i think the admin tried to create a CNAME but i saw today that there is a precise procedure to do that too that he might not have been aware of. I'll look into that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enable that and make it work, I think you'll have to add this Google App Engine app to your Google Apps domain dashboard. To achieve that you will have to manage the mycompany.com domain with Google Apps first. After that if you go to https://appengine.google.com > locate your app > Application Settings > Add Domain and follow the steps there.

Once you will see your GAE app in the Google Apps dashboard, you might also going to need to add some stuff in the `app.yaml` to be able to restrict your users:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.py
  login: required
```

After redeploying the app the access should be restricted to only your desired domain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will talk about it with the admin. However, i don't quite understand what "manage the domain with Google Apps" implies. Is it just about allowing them to create sub-domains...  or must the domain name be "registered" (not the word i am looking for exactly, sorry, my english is getting rusty) by google ?

Comment: @girardid You will have to read carefully this thing:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain I hope it will clear some things for you

Comment: Thanks, i'll go trough this with the admin and keep you posted.

Comment: And it works :) So here's what's been done : Simply adding my app identifier to the list of authorised apps in the Google Apps Control Panel + of course what @Lipis said (adding the `login: required` line in the `app.yaml`). We are now waiting for our domain provider to create de CNAME and everything will be fine. Thank you.

Comment: how to give login:required, incase of java, in appengine-web.xml