# Trouble Viewing GAE Version, Error: Server Error

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I am having some difficulty viewing a deployed version on GAE.

From the versions screen of the GAE console I can click the version and it opens a new tab to my web application. Instead of displaying the application though, it displays the following message:

[image]
Upon seeing this message I decided to go read the logs. The log corresponding the request made to the page reads as follows:

> Authentication for the Google Apps domain ***my application*** can only be
>   performed when requests are served from a subdomain of that domain or
>   it has been approved through the Google Apps Control Panel. See
>   https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth

In fact, when I click on any of the available versions, this same error happens. For the production version there is a sub-domain set up where everything gets routed to. I [read a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495047/domain-restricted-authentication-on-google-app-engine#answer) that suggested to add a new domain, however this also did not work during the verification process. Furthermore, for this particular version of the application I would much rather be able to avoid having to set up a sub-domain and just be able to hit the version URL.

Does anyone have any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, all I needed to do was to go to the settings and switch the authentication from ***Google Apps Domain*** to ***google Accounts API***